# return float when + class

Tags: c++, object

I was trying to take float + objected class and have the result return as float, however, my code just does not work. I am pretty confused. I have added that overload function as a friend to the class. could anyone explain it to me?
With the best regards

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
using namespace std;
#define MAX_NUM_SENSORS 5
enum { INVALID, TEMPERATURE, HUMIDTY };

// The 'Sensors' structure describes a single sensor, it's type and current value.
//   type - describes the type of sensor 0 (INVALID), 1 (TEMPERATURE), 2 (HUMIDITY)
//   value - the current value of the sensor.
//   valid - set to TRUE if the sensor is valid, should default to FALSE until set up.
class Sensors
{
public:
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream&, const Sensors&);
    friend float operator+ (float,const Sensors&);
private:
    int type;
    float value;
    bool valid = false;
};
ostream& operator<<(ostream& OutStream, const Sensors& OutComp)
{
    OutStream << " Type: " << (OutComp.type == TEMPERATURE ? "Temperature" : "Humidity");
    OutStream << " Value: " << OutComp.value << endl;
    return OutStream;
}
float operator+ (float adding, const Sensors& added)
{
    float sum;
    sum = added.value + adding;
    return sum;
}
int main()
{
    Sensors tested();
    float m = 1.2 + tested;
    cout << m;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: what is the meaning of "not work" ?

Comment: `Sensors::value` is never initialized

Comment: did you read warnings and errors ? https://godbolt.org/z/hvj3qWeez

Comment: yeap, my silly mistake. I took the code out of the larger project and test it part by part, so I was not looking at the sensors initially. thank you to help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code in [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:28,endLineNumber:36,positionColumn:22,positionLineNumber:35,selectionStartColumn:28,selectionStartLineNumber:36,startColumn:22,startLineNumber:35),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccstdint%3E%0Ausing+namespace+std%3B%0A%23define+MAX_NUM_SENSORS+5%0Aenum+%7B+INVALID,+TEMPERATURE,+HUMIDTY+%7D%3B%0A%0A//+The+!%27Sensors!%27+structure+describes+a+single+sensor,+it!%27s+type+and+current+value.%0A//+++type+-+describes+the+type+of+sensor+0+(INVALID),+1+(TEMPERATURE),+2+(HUMIDITY)%0A//+++value+-+the+current+value+of+the+sensor.%0A//+++valid+-+set+to+TRUE+if+the+sensor+is+valid,+should+default+to+FALSE+until+set+up.%0Aclass+Sensors%0A%7B%0Apublic:%0A++++friend+ostream%26+operator+%3C%3C(ostream%26,+const+Sensors%26)%3B%0A++++friend+float+operator%2B+(float,const+Sensors%26)%3B%0Aprivate:%0A++++int+type%3B%0A++++float+value%3B%0A++++bool+valid+%3D+false%3B%0A%7D%3B%0Aostream%26+operator%3C%3C(ostream%26+OutStream,+const+Sensors%26+OutComp)%0A%7B%0A++++OutStream+%3C%3C+%22+Type:+%22+%3C%3C+(OutComp.type+%3D%3D+TEMPERATURE+%3F+%22Temperature%22+:+%22Humidity%22)%3B%0A++++OutStream+%3C%3C+%22+Value:+%22+%3C%3C+OutComp.value+%3C%3C+endl%3B%0A++++return+OutStream%3B%0A%7D%0Afloat+operator%2B+(float+adding,+const+Sensors%26+added)%0A%7B%0A++++float+sum%3B%0A++++sum+%3D+added.value+%2B+adding%3B%0A++++return+sum%3B%0A%7D%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++Sensors+tested()%3B%0A++++float+m+%3D+1.2+%2B+tested%3B%0A++++cout+%3C%3C+m%3B%0A++++return+1%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:54.65570792389582,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g112,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:boost,ver:%27177%27)),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B2a%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+11.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:13.62301592739246,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%270%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+11.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:31.721276148711745,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

There is some kind of simple fixes.

```cpp
int main()
{
    Sensors tested();
    //            ^--- remove this parenthesis (or use braces, it's ambigious)
    float m = 1.2 + tested;
    //        ^----- This is a double, change this to "1.2f"
    cout << m;
    return 1;
}
```

Decimal values in code is double by default, you need to add the postfix f to specify that it is a float. Or you could add a definition of operator + with double as a parameter.

[Here](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:29,endLineNumber:36,positionColumn:29,positionLineNumber:36,selectionStartColumn:29,selectionStartLineNumber:36,startColumn:29,startLineNumber:36),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccstdint%3E%0Ausing+namespace+std%3B%0A%23define+MAX_NUM_SENSORS+5%0Aenum+%7B+INVALID,+TEMPERATURE,+HUMIDTY+%7D%3B%0A%0A//+The+!%27Sensors!%27+structure+describes+a+single+sensor,+it!%27s+type+and+current+value.%0A//+++type+-+describes+the+type+of+sensor+0+(INVALID),+1+(TEMPERATURE),+2+(HUMIDITY)%0A//+++value+-+the+current+value+of+the+sensor.%0A//+++valid+-+set+to+TRUE+if+the+sensor+is+valid,+should+default+to+FALSE+until+set+up.%0Aclass+Sensors%0A%7B%0Apublic:%0A++++friend+ostream%26+operator+%3C%3C(ostream%26,+const+Sensors%26)%3B%0A++++friend+float+operator%2B+(float,const+Sensors%26)%3B%0Aprivate:%0A++++int+type%3B%0A++++float+value%3B%0A++++bool+valid+%3D+false%3B%0A%7D%3B%0Aostream%26+operator%3C%3C(ostream%26+OutStream,+const+Sensors%26+OutComp)%0A%7B%0A++++OutStream+%3C%3C+%22+Type:+%22+%3C%3C+(OutComp.type+%3D%3D+TEMPERATURE+%3F+%22Temperature%22+:+%22Humidity%22)%3B%0A++++OutStream+%3C%3C+%22+Value:+%22+%3C%3C+OutComp.value+%3C%3C+endl%3B%0A++++return+OutStream%3B%0A%7D%0Afloat+operator%2B+(float+adding,+const+Sensors%26+added)%0A%7B%0A++++float+sum%3B%0A++++sum+%3D+added.value+%2B+adding%3B%0A++++return+sum%3B%0A%7D%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++Sensors+tested%3B%0A++++float+m+%3D+1.2f+%2B+tested%3B%0A++++cout+%3C%3C+m%3B%0A++++return+1%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:54.65570792389582,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g112,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:boost,ver:%27177%27)),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B2a%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+11.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:13.62301592739246,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%270%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+11.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:31.721276148711745,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) is a compiling version of your code